# Example of an undecidable that is not NP-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory

Can someone give me an example of an undecidable problem that is not NP-hard?

I'm unable to understand the difference between the two.

Thanks very much!

Comment: [Did you read this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494133/relationship-between-np-hard-and-undecidable-problems)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming.

Comment: Could you help me out with this question instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **NP-hard** problem is one such that every problem in NP can be reduced to it. In fact, it is "at least as hard as" the problems in NP class. For example, TSP (Traveling Sales Person) is NP-hard. However, **undecidable** is a problem for which there is no algorithm that always decide correctly. For example, the question of whether a program halts at some point or not is undecidable. In fact, you may not have an algorithm that can answer this question correctly for all programs in the world. (This can be proved)

So, in brief, an undecidable problem is **logically hard**; no matter how strong your computers or algorithms are, they cannot be solved. But, NP-hard problems have algorithms to be solved with but those algorithms are not polynomial in time.